# What ability allows a divine character to have an alignment opposed to their god?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, cleric, alignment, content-identification

I recall hearing of a feat, alternate class feature, etc. that allowed for a cleric to be of an opposing alignment from their god, for example a Good Paladin of an evil god, achaotic cleric of a lawful god, etc.

Unfortunately, I've completely forgotten any further details on the ability.  What ability am I thinking of?

Comment: For reference, this is the *default* in the Eberron campaign setting.

Comment: @KRyan Sort of. It's true that Eberron Clerics are permitted to be of alignments that differ from those of their deities, but having the same alignment as one's deity is still the norm, even if it's optional. Also, only clerics are allowed to have alignments that differ from their gods'; Eberron Paladins and Druids have the same ol' alignment restrictions as ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The untyped [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) feat **Heretic of the Faith** (*Power of Faerûn* 46-7), among other effects, allows a cleric's "alignment [to] be two steps away from [the cleric's] respective deity’s alignment instead of just one" as is typically required of a cleric. (See [Cleric](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/cleric.html#_top) on Alignment on *Player's Handbook* 30 and 31 for details.)

For example, the feat allows a cleric of the LE Faerûnian god [Bane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Forgotten_Realms_deities#Greater_deities) to be not only LE, LN, or NE but also either LG or CE. (As Bane himself isn't true neutral, a cleric of Bane still can't be *only* neutral in alignment.)

The feat Heretic of the Faith, however, comes with *a lot* of baggage. For example, the feat mandates following a *particular* heresy (and this is *not* typically a heresy developed *by* the PC!), *and* the feat typically leaves the heretic's soul forever damned unless the heresy is later deemed acceptable by the church faithful *and* the deity (a situation the text refers to as "vanishingly rare"). O, and, of course, most members of the heretic's traditional church despise the heretic *and* religious followers that had already been gained from the feat [Leadership](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#leadership) (*PH* 97) may leave the heretic when the feat's gained.

Several heresies are described in *Power of Faerûn*, and the *Dragon* #355 Volo’s Guide column “Demon Cults of the Realms” describes the Harlot’s Coin Heresy, a heresy of Waukeen.

No guidelines are provided for adjudicating this feat's effects in a setting other than the Forgotten Realms. Sadly, this makes it difficult to evaluate the feat's interaction with likely the most popular *fan-created* heresy, the [Burning Hate](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929063558/http://community.wizards.com/comment/13724166) heresy of the World of Greyhawk god [Pelor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelor).

---

***Note:*** Also worth mentioning also is the Complete Scoundrel *prestige class **gray guard** (40-5), which at level 1 gains the class feature sacrament of trust that allows others that cast on the gray guard the spell* [atonement](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsAtoB.html#atonement) *to do so at reduced cost. At level 10 the gray guard gains the class feature sacrament of the true faith, allowing a gray guard to violate his code of conduct without risking losing his paladin special abilities unless such violations are egregious or pervasive. However, a paladin/gray guard must still remain lawful good.*